# How do I sync my passwords between browsers?

Tags: browser, sync

I tried xBrowserSync but it does not work properly, is there any other alternatives for syncing passwords between browsers? (specifically Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: I do not think browsers will sync passwords. Very insecure. Use one of the mainstream password managers.

Answer (score 1):

xBrowserSync is for bookmark syncing (which is great), not passwords.

If you want to try a Freemium, online solution there is [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/pricing)
I prefer [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) as a free, offline solution.

Comment: LastPass can be used free to. I use it and its great.

Comment: @LPChip That's correct. I updated with a link to its features matrix and pricing.